# How to record macro in powerpoint 2013

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to record macro in 2013 but after i turn off powerpoint and start it again macro disappears.

I am trying to make some kind of powerpoint template and add it to every new presentation automatically.

Comment: As far as I am concern, Powerpoint allows to run Macro but, does not allow to record a Macro. But try once as our friend @Siddharth Sawjiani is suggesting.

Comment: As I know you can not write macro directly on slides because PPT does not allow to write macro directly on slides.

Comment: Somehow the question title does not fit to the description text: you want to record a macro or make a macro available for all files? In case 2 you can deploy a macro by creating a PowerPoint Add-In.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

1) Open the file where the macro is saved.

2) Go to File -> Options -> Customize Toolbar

[image]

3) Under Choose commands from, select Macros

4) Add the Macro under a new group

[image]

It should appear on the Home ribbon every time you open PowerPoint

[image]

Comment: The file in which the macro is originally saved, should be open in the background

Comment: The question was 'How to record macro in powerpoint 2013' and the answer does not solve this issue.

Comment: The question was 'How to record macro in powerpoint 2013' and the answer does not solve this issue.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is off-track...  the second part of the OP's question is answered by this, and the OP accepted this

Comment: hmmmm ....  but it doesn't seem to work...  there is indeed an item in the ribbon,  but the macro is missing if I open a new file....

Answer (score 13):

Not available any more since 2010 version. Write your own vba script instead.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just putting it here: you can't record macros any more :(

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-macro-in-PowerPoint-5b07aff6-4dc9-462f-8fc9-66b4c5344e7e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving in a macro-enabled format? If not, macros/modules will disappear when you close the presentation.

To save in a macro-enabled format ...

1. Click on the "Files" tab
2. Select "Save As"
3. Choose a location
4. In the dialog box that opens, click on the "Save as type" drop-down menu
5. Select "PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Presentation (*.pptm)" or "PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Template (*.potm)"

There's no way (that I know of) to automatically add the macros/modules directly INTO new presentations, what you need to do is create a new PowerPoint template and save the macros in it (using the *.potm file format above).

I don't think there's a "personal presentation" in PowerPoint like there is in excel, so you'll have to make sure the template is open/loaded for the macros to be available to other presentations. You can set a template as the default one for PowerPoint (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Load-and-apply-a-personal-template-71262c90-1447-4109-90f3-eb84f9d06c98), but this won't work if you work with multiple different templates. The other option is to have the user manually open the template every time they open PowerPoint.

Cheers